# MongoDB Meteor.js Increment var from a var in another document

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, var

I have something like this:

I can't seem to be able to modify multiple documents a the same time.

```
click: function() {
      var power = Meteor.user().power;
      var mult = Meteor.user().mult;
      Meteor.users.update({
                  _id: this.userId
              }, {
                  $inc: {
                      'money': power * mult,
                      'lifetimeclick': 1,
                      'done': 0,
                      'done2': 0,
                      'done3': 0,

                  },
```

How would I make it so that it changes the var of another document at the same time.
Please tell me if there are any other snippets you need to see or whether or not something is unclear to you.

I want it to be so when you click the button, it increments the current user's variables and the variable of another set user that I have already made.

I have tried many things but I have no idea what format to use or how to go about doing this.

I want the function to take a variable from 1 document and add it to a variable in another document. The only thing I know how to do is to add variables in one document.

Comment: Can you explain "the var of another document at the same time"? Which other document? It's helpful if you could show the initial state and the expected state.

Comment: Alright so I have user accounts store as documents. I want it so that it modifies two documents with one function. Using a variable in the first document as what to modify in the second.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you expect multiple documents in the collection to meet your query criteria, and you want to update each of those documents? If that's the case you need to set [the multi parameter.](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/#multi-parameter)

`DB.update( _id: theId, { $inc: { value: 1}}, { multi: true});`

Comment: Note that `multi` only works server-side. Also if the query is by `_id` as shown here then there will only ever be one document.